# Apigility Custom Db Filter Based on oAuth Request

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'm building a REST DB connected system where users can only create/fetch/query their own data based on the client_id or user_id doesn't matter. I've successfully implemented oAuth and Mapper/Resource objects to go along with my Entity/Collection. After a successful oAuth request using an access token is there a recommended way to get the client_id or user_id so I can filter database queries based on who made the request?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. a simple solution is in the API config inject an instance of \ZF\MvcAuth\Identity\AuthenticatedIdentity into the service mapper.

```
if ($sm->has('api-identity')) {
    $mapper->setAuthenticatedIdentity($sm->get('api-identity'));
} else {
    $mapper->setAuthenticatedIdentity(new \ZF\MvcAuth\Identity\AuthenticatedIdentity());
}
```

In the Mapper add setter/getters.

```
protected $authenticatedIdentity;

public function setAuthenticatedIdentity(\ZF\MvcAuth\Identity\AuthenticatedIdentity $authenticatedIdentity)
{
    $this->authenticatedIdentity = $authenticatedIdentity;
}

protected function getAuthenticatedIdentity()
{
    return $this->authenticatedIdentity;
}
```

Finally.

```
print_r(get_class_methods($this->getAuthenticatedIdentity()));
```